# Can facebook verify IDs for me?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I see that Facebook has Identity Verification tools for their own users, is it possible to poll their API and determine whether or not a User has had their id verified?  I'm assuming we'll have to get permissions to access this information as well as access their names.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One quick look at the docs tells you that there is a "is_verified" field, no need for extra permissions:

```
/me?fields=is_verified,name
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user

Comment: Never looked at the docs before other than spending some time today poking around trying to figure them out.  I did spend a couple hours trying to figure that out but didn't know where to look.

I really appreciate the advice.. and maybe it wasn't you but it's those downvotes and attitude that I'm supposed to know everything already that are the reason why stackoverflow isn't as active and helpful to new programmers as it otherwise could have been.

Comment: stackoverflow people are VERY helpful, but you are required to do some research before asking. a serious developer always tries to figure stuff out on his own - and in most cases he will succeed without asking on stackoverflow, and learn a lot more in the process ;)

Comment: you know, "how can i do xy" or "is it possible to do xy" is just way too broad. there´s no shortcut, and stackoverflow is not a school. it´s a place where developers ask questions after they did some research. i do understand that it may be hard for beginners, but we´ve all been there and we´ve all spent days and weeks to learn the basics ;) - i guess it´s also because a lot of people learned programming with books, nowadays everything is available on the internet with one google search...